# How do I implement Post-redirect-get on Google App Engine with Python?

Tags: form-submit, post-redirect-get

I am developing an online bidding system on Google App Engine with Python. Regarding the post-redirect-get mechanism, I've been googling a while and still have no clear idea of how to implement it. Suppose:

HTML:

```
<form action="/test" method="post">
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Python:

```
# Collect data from the posted form
...
# Save data into datastore
...
# Prepare template values

tempalteValues = { ... }
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/', 'responseMessage.html')
handler.response.out.write(template.render(path, templateValues))

# Then what?
```

I have two questions:

1) After rendering the response message file, what should I do next? That is, how to implement the 'GET'?

2) Another strategy I can think of is: If the post is supposed to happen only once (e.g., product purchasing with a unique order number), can I set a flag in the entity indicating that the form has been submitted and the following posts will be ignored if the flag is set? Is this feasible or even correct?

(Note: because the order number is generated by the system, the entity has to be saved before the form submission in order to get that number)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is building a Restful service something like this:

```
class BiddingHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        #Get code goes here for this handler

    def post(self):
        #code that gets your posted data and processes it

    def delete(self):
        #code to delete something

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/bidding', BiddingHandler)])
```

Looking at the above if you wanted to do a redirect after making a post in the last line of your post instead of rendering a template you would simply redirect the user to the get part of the handler with the following line:

```
self.response.redirect('/bidding')
```

What I have shown you above is the correct way to implement it. Writing to the datastore and reading from it for every request would mean more overhead and costs.

Comment: Hey, I didn't expect such a simple solution. Very nice and thanks a million, Tkingovr.

Comment: Same here I ran into the same issue at one point and didn't believe it was this simple glad I could help!

Comment: I have no problem in the post-redirect-get path, but I have trouble in delete-redirect-get path. After delete process completed, I simply self.rediret_to('my-handler-name') like that in my post method, but what I got is another delete instead of get. (means delete-redirect-delete instead of delete-redirect-get) Do you meet similar situation?

Comment: After I read [302 Found](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3) and [303 See Other](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4), I know I should return status code 303 instead of 302. So change to self.redirect_to('my-handler-name', _code=303) can get what I want.